# Trying to pass the DocumentID from a ListView to ¨ Like ¨ Function

Tags: flutter, dart

Im using a ListView to display all the posts i got from Firebase, and them send the DocumentID of a especial post to a ¨like¨ function when the user press the button, but im getting the following error:

```
I/flutter (28036): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE 
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (28036): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (28036): Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'documentId'.
I/flutter (28036): Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
I/flutter (28036): Tried calling: documentId
```

Already tried to change to ¨documentid¨,¨documentId´ and ¨documentID¨

This is my code from the Button:

```
onPressed: () => likes(                                                     
  snapshot.data.documentId),
```

And this is my code from the function:

```
void likes(String documentid) async {
    await db
        .collection('messages')
        .document(documentid)
        .updateData({'likes': FieldValue.increment(1)});
  }
```

This is how i build the ListView:

```
new StreamBuilder(
          stream: db
              .collection('messages')
              .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 400.0,
                    child: ListView.builder(
... its working, but i dont know how to get the documentID from it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i did to correct the error:

```
onPressed: (){

likes(snapshot.data.documents[position].documentID);
                                                  }



void likes(documentid) async {
await db
    .collection('messages')
    .document(documentid)
    .updateData({'likes': FieldValue.increment(1)});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have a **documentId** in the **snapshot.data**.
try logging the snapshot.data to check for it.

**Edit to add code**
change this

```
onPressed: () => likes(                                                     
  snapshot.data.documentId),
```

to

```
onPressed: ()
{
  print(snapshot.data.toString());
  likes(snapshot.data.documentId);
}
```

Comment: Plz, can you explain how i can logg it? Im using VS Code

Comment: there is a log() method in the developers library just do `log(snapshot.data.toString())`